# Fortran C binding -Linking errror LNK2019: unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, binding, fortran

I have a Fortran code that has to call the Clipper Library, for which I downloaded and I compile the original C++ source code. I have written a wrapping subroutine in C++ that reads:

```
 extern "C" void wrapUNIintersNM(
     int Ndry[1],
     double xclip[5],
     double yclip[5],
     double POLYStoBEjoinedX[13][100],
     double POLYStoBEjoinedY[13][100],
     int NPOLYtoBEjoined[1],
     int VERTtoBEjoined[13],
     double POLYSunionX[13][100],
     double POLYSunionY[13][100],
     int NPOLYSunion[1],
     int VERTunion[13],
     double POLYintersX[13][100],
     double POLYintersY[13][100],
     int NPOLYSinters[1],
     int VERTinters[13],
     double absMAXx[1],
     double absMAXy[1])
 {
     ............
     ............
 }
```

I created a module for the binding:

```
module Cplusplus
use,intrinsic :: ISO_C_Binding


interface
    subroutine wrapUNIintersNM(Ndry,xclip,yclip,&
                  POLYStoBEjoinedX,POLYStoBEjoinedY,NPOLYStoBEjoined,VERTtoBEjoined,&
                  POLYSunionX,POLYSunionY,NPOLYSunion,VERTunion, & 
                  POLYintersX,POLYintersY,NPOLYSinters,VERTinters,&
                  absMAXx,absMAXy) bind(C,name="wrapUNIintersNM") ! bind(C,name="wrapperClipper") add name if you wanna retain uppercase letter, otherwise are all made lowercase and C++ is case sensitive
      import :: c_double, c_int
      real(kind=c_double), dimension(5) :: xclip,yclip
      real(kind=c_double), dimension(100,13) :: POLYintersX,POLYintersY,POLYStoBEjoinedX,POLYStoBEjoinedY,&
                                                POLYSunionX,POLYSunionY 
      real(kind=c_double) :: absMAXx(1),absMAXy(1)
      integer(kind=c_int), dimension(13) :: VERTinters,VERTunion,VERTtoBEjoined
      integer(kind=c_int) :: Ndry,NPOLYStoBEjoined,NPOLYSinters,NPOLYSunion
    end subroutine
end interface 

end module Cplusplus
```

I have a subroutine update that calls wrapUNIintersNM this way

```
       subroutine update
       use Cplusplus

       .........
       ...........
         CALL wrapUNIintersNM(Ndry,xclip,yclip, &
                     POLYStoBEjoinedX,POLYStoBEjoinedY,NPOLYStoBEjoined,VERTtoBEjoined,&  !polygons to join (union)
                     POLYSunionX,POLYSunionY,NPOLYSunion,VERTunion, & !union of polygons 
                     POLYintersX,POLYintersY,NPOLYSinters,VERTinters,&                       !intersection of union  
                     absMAXx,absMAXy)    
        ..........
        ...........
        return 
        end
```

Everything compiles fine, but at a linking stage I get this error:

```
 error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals  example.dll
 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _wrapUNIintersNM referenced in function _UPDATE
```

Any suggestion?
thanks

Comment: Are you linking in the library?

Comment: Isn't your problem just that your Fortran compiler is prepending underscores to names and your C++ compiler is not?  Try renaming your wrapper function `extern "C" void _wrapUNIintersNM`.

Comment: @Tom That shouldn't hapoen if he is compiling the code he shows. Alberto, You will have to show how do you compile it and preferably some full compilable example.

Comment: That depends on the compiler and options used.

Comment: Looking at the error message, the Fortran compiler is emitting a reference to the symbol `_wrapUNIintersNM` - ie definitely prepending and underscore.  The only question is whether the C compiler does the same.

Comment: Thanks to all. IanH you sent me to the right direction. I added the path to  "Additional library directory", but I did not put the name of the library in the additional dependency. I thought it was not necessary and a search was performed in the directory. Problem solved,thanks.